# Hide other tabs's content and display only the selected tab's content

Tags: jquery

I need to only display only the selected tab's content.

You can see my code in that pen https://codepen.io/Laurentfrom47/pen/mYJZVx

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.list-items").children(".item-details").hide();
    $(".list-items").click(function(){
        $(this).children("div").toggle(50);
        icon = $(this).find("span");
        icon.toggleClass("icon");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if click LI 's div is visible and show / hide accordingly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li.list-items").children(".item-details").hide();
  $(".list-items").click(function() {
    $("li.list-items").children("div.item-details").hide(50);
    $(this).children("div.item-details").is(":visible") ? $(this).children("div.item-details").hide(50) : $(this).children("div.item-details").show(50); //show hide according to div's visiblitiy
    $(".list-items").removeClass('icon')
    icon = $(this).find("span");
    icon.hasClass("icon") ? icon.removeClass("icon") : icon.addClass("icon"); //show hide according to div's visiblitiy
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}

.list-items {
  margin: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  .head {
    display: block;
    background-color: #dedede;
    padding: 10px;
    span {
      float: right;
      color: green;
      &.icon {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
  .item-details {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list-items">
    <a class="head">Tab 1 <span>icon</span></a>
    <div class="item-details">
      Hi you are in Tab 1
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae urna fermentum, tempus leo sit amet, accumsan nunc. Maecenas scelerisque elementum lectus, vitae tempus ante pretium et. Aliquam blandit enim et dolor consectetur, quis accumsan
        nisi facilisis. In ut arcu ex. Donec id turpis cursus, gravida urna pharetra, suscipit odio. Sed malesuada quam vel felis vestibulum venenatis. Duis magna arcu, ultricies ac libero quis, ultricies venenatis ex. Duis imperdiet venenatis eros, placerat
        congue lectus. Proin interdum nisi eu luctus pharetra. Nunc molestie commodo purus, dapibus sagittis neque tristique ac. Phasellus ullamcorper tincidunt lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
        Suspendisse potenti. Etiam quis orci efficitur, volutpat enim vitae, cursus magna. Curabitur viverra tortor quis dolor bibendum luctus. Phasellus et risus ac turpis blandit ornare.</p>

    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="list-items">
    <a class="head">Tab 2 <span>icon</span></a>
    <div class="item-details">
      Hi you are in Tab 2
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae urna fermentum, tempus leo sit amet, accumsan nunc. Maecenas scelerisque elementum lectus, vitae tempus ante pretium et. Aliquam blandit enim et dolor consectetur, quis accumsan
        nisi facilisis. In ut arcu ex. Donec id turpis cursus, gravida urna pharetra, suscipit odio. Sed malesuada quam vel felis vestibulum venenatis. Duis magna arcu, ultricies ac libero quis, ultricies venenatis ex. Duis imperdiet venenatis eros, placerat
        congue lectus. Proin interdum nisi eu luctus pharetra. Nunc molestie commodo purus, dapibus sagittis neque tristique ac. Phasellus ullamcorper tincidunt lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
        Suspendisse potenti. Etiam quis orci efficitur, volutpat enim vitae, cursus magna. Curabitur viverra tortor quis dolor bibendum luctus. Phasellus et risus ac turpis blandit ornare.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-items">
    <a class="head">Tab 3 <span>icon</span></a>
    <div class="item-details">
      Hi you are in Tab 3
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae urna fermentum, tempus leo sit amet, accumsan nunc. Maecenas scelerisque elementum lectus, vitae tempus ante pretium et. Aliquam blandit enim et dolor consectetur, quis accumsan
        nisi facilisis. In ut arcu ex. Donec id turpis cursus, gravida urna pharetra, suscipit odio. Sed malesuada quam vel felis vestibulum venenatis. Duis magna arcu, ultricies ac libero quis, ultricies venenatis ex. Duis imperdiet venenatis eros, placerat
        congue lectus. Proin interdum nisi eu luctus pharetra. Nunc molestie commodo purus, dapibus sagittis neque tristique ac. Phasellus ullamcorper tincidunt lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
        Suspendisse potenti. Etiam quis orci efficitur, volutpat enim vitae, cursus magna. Curabitur viverra tortor quis dolor bibendum luctus. Phasellus et risus ac turpis blandit ornare.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is perfect just only a little problem with icon class, it is not close when you click on another tab.

Comment: @Laurent try this updated answer same concept with the hiding of the div

Comment: happy coding mate

Comment: Sorry, a little problem when you open a tab and you click on another tab the class icon is not remove from the first clicked tab.

Answer (score 1):

Hide other contents in the event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.list-items").children(".item-details").hide();
    $(".list-items").click(function(){
        $("li.list-items").children(".item-details").hide(); // hide content
        $("li.list-items").find("span.icon").toggleClass("icon"); // close tab
        $(this).children("div").toggle(50);
        icon = $(this).find("span");
        icon.toggleClass("icon");
    });
});
```

Comment: OK thanks but also on new tab click the tab must closed.

Answer (score 0):

I've just re-written your `Script` Section. Check this out if it fulfills your target.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li.list-items").children(".item-details").hide();        
  $(".list-items").click(function(e){
    if($(this).children("div").css('display') == "block"){
      $(this).children("div").toggle(80);
      icon = $(this).find("span");
      icon.toggleClass("icon");
    }
    else{
      $(".list-items").each(function(){          
        $(this).children('div').hide();
        $(this).find("span").removeClass('icon');
      });
      $(this).children("div").toggle(80);
      icon = $(this).find("span");
      icon.toggleClass("icon");
    }
  });
});
```